# $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(ax)}{x},$ knowing the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

If we know that
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(x)}{x}}\rightarrow c,\; \text{ for a given }c\in\mathbb{R}.$$ Show that
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(ax)}{x}}\rightarrow ac\; \text{ for any } a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}}.
$$

We definitely know from the above (using the product rule for limits) 
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x)}\rightarrow 0 \;\;\text{ holds. }
$$
 Don't know if that helps.

Comment: Hint: defining $y = ax$, we have $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{f(ax)}{x} = \lim\limits_{y\to 0}\frac{f(y)}{y/a}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is elementary, this may require an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

We want to make the following quantity small:

$$\left|\frac{f(ax)}{x}-ac\right|$$

Observe that

$$\left|\frac{f(ax)}{x}-ac\right|= \left|\frac{f(ax)}{ax}a-ac\right|= |a|\left|\frac{f(ax)}{ax}-c\right|$$

and this last factor can be made small because $f(x)/x \to c$. It is a good exercise on this level to make this into a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Consider $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(ax)}{ax}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{{f(ax)}\over x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}a{{f(ax)}\over {ax}}=ac$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)\over x}=l$$therefore $$\lim_{x\to 0}{f(ax)\over x}=\lim_{x\to 0}a{f(ax)\over ax}=a\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)\over x}=al$$